Seeking Guidance on HttpResponseJsonExtensions.cs WriteAsJsonAsync Method and RFC 9457 Compliance in .NET 8 Web API
I am currently working on a .NET 8 Web API application and have recently integrated the Global Exception Handler feature using IExceptionHandler. I referred to the latest release notes on ASP.NET Core 8.0 and utilized the following online resources for implementation guidance: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-8.0?view=aspnetcore-8.0)
I implemented Global Exception Handler for .NET 8 Web API application. For reference purpose I used https://code-maze.com/dotnet-use-iexceptionhandler-to-handle-exceptions/ and https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/global-exception-handling-in-aspnet-core/.
In these examples, and in most others that I have found, the WriteAsJsonAsync method from the HttpResponseJsonExtensions.cs class (namespace: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http) is extensively used. This method writes the specified value as JSON to the response body and sets the response content-type to application/json; charset=utf-8.
However, I have encountered an issue. As per RFC 9457 (RFC 9457), we are required to set the content-type value as application/problem+json. Unfortunately, the WriteAsJsonAsync method seems to be overriding this content-type value.
I am looking for any alternative methods or solutions that do not override the content-type and abide by the RFC 9457 standards. Any insights, recommendations, or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Code :
internal class GlobalExceptionHandler(ILogger logger, IWebHostEnvironment env) : IExceptionHandler
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger = logger.ForContext<GlobalExceptionHandler>();
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env = env.IsNotNull();

    public async ValueTask<bool> TryHandleAsync(HttpContext httpContext,
        Exception exception,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var errorResult = exception switch
        {
            FluentValidation.ValidationException fluentException => ExceptionDetails.HandleFluentValidationException(fluentException),
            UnauthorizedException unauthorizedException => ExceptionDetails.HandleUnauthorizedException(unauthorizedException),
            ForbiddenException forbiddenException => ExceptionDetails.HandleForbiddenException(forbiddenException),
            NotFoundException notFoundException => ExceptionDetails.HandleNotFoundException(notFoundException),
            TimeOutException timeOutException => ExceptionDetails.HandleTimeOutException(timeOutException),
            _ => ExceptionDetails.HandleDefaultException(exception),
        };

        var errorLogLevel = exception switch
        {
            FluentValidation.ValidationException or UnauthorizedException => LogEventLevel.Warning,
            _ => LogEventLevel.Error
        };

        LogErrorMessage(errorLogLevel, exception, errorResult);

        var response = httpContext.Response;
        if (!response.HasStarted)
        {
            response.StatusCode = errorResult.Status!.Value;
            response.ContentType = "application/problem+json";
            await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(errorResult, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);            
            
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.Warning("Can't write error response. Response has already started.");
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void LogErrorMessage(LogEventLevel errorLogLevel, Exception exception, ExceptionDetails details)
    {
        using (LogContext.PushProperty("TraceId", details.TraceId))
        using (LogContext.PushProperty("Errors", details.Errors))
        {
            if (_env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                LogContext.PushProperty("StackTrace", exception.StackTrace!.Trim());
            }

            _logger.Write(errorLogLevel, "{title} | {details} | {traceId}", details.Title, details.Detail, details.TraceId);
        }
    }
}

Can anyone please help me here by providing their guidance? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

You can use the the following HttpResponseJsonExtensions.WriteAsJsonAsync() overload:
WriteAsJsonAsync<TValue>(HttpResponse, TValue, JsonSerializerOptions, string contentType, CancellationToken)

Write the specified value as JSON to the response body. The response content-type will be set to the specified content-type.
Applies to: ASP.NET Core 7.0 and later.

Thus your code should look like:
response.StatusCode = errorResult.Status!.Value;
await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(errorResult, 
                                default(JsonSerializerOptions),
                                contentType : "application/problem+json",
                                cancellationToken)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);   

Mockup fiddle here.

Thanks @dbc for your response :). I was was to fix the issue now.
